# Primefaces autocomplete dropdown fade away, disappear after clicking on scroll bar

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces autocomplete dropdown fade away, disappear after clicking on scroll bar
[image: dropdown]

To get this functionality I use `scrollHeight = "300"`

```
                    <p:autoComplete
                            id="other-tax-payer-country"
                            class="form-input custom-autocomplete"
                            queryDelay="300"
                            value="#{cabinetFormView.tmpTaxCountry}"
                            completeMethod="#{cabinetFormView.getTaxCountriesList}"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            var="t" itemValue="#{t}" itemLabel="#{t}"
                            onclick="PF('dlg2').search('')" widgetVar="dlg2"
                            converter="countryDtoConverter" scrollHeight = "300">
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{t}" />
                            </p:column>
                        <f:ajax onevent="validateTaxPayerFields" event="itemSelect" listener="#{cabinetFormView.addTaxCountry}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Please, add relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces autocomplete close after click on scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443642/primefaces-autocomplete-close-after-click-on-scroll-bar)