# Primefaces autocomplete close after click on scroll bar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.2.

My problem is when I use autoComplete with `dropDown=true` and `scrollHeight`. Window close after I click on scroll bar. It works fine when I just use wheel on my mouse.

```
<p:autoComplete id="agendaSelect" scrollHeight="100" completeMethod="#{agendaAutoCompleteView.completeAgenda}" dropdown="true" itemValue="#{agenda}" var="agenda" itemLabel="#{agenda.displayName}" forceSelection="true" value="#{agendaAutoCompleteView.agenda}" converter="agendaConverter" required="true" requiredMessage="Pole Agenda musi byt vyplnene.">                           
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="bunkaSelect" listener="#{bunkaAutoCompleteView.bunkaListener}" />                          
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: without a scrollHeight it works? DoDoes it work in 6.1?

Comment: If I dont use scrollHeight there is not scroll bar. It doesnt work in 6.1 neiher.

Comment: The fix for this bug was checked in a year ago, but still no v6.3 and no patch release either. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3431

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As temporary fix until the Bug is fixed you might use the following JS-Code somewhere on your page (e.g. upon onload).

```js
$('body').on('mousedown', '.ui-autocomplete-panel', function(event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation();});
```

This would prevent the event currently leading to misbehaviour (closing the panel) to be carried out. It will work also for partial Requests/Responses as the event would be applied to future DOM Elements of the same class.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user3437084: if this is what you needed and it helped you, you should upvote the answer!

Comment: I already did, you just cant see it because I dont have 5 points yet.

Answer (score 1):

Able to fix this by adding below class.

```
.ui-corner-all{
padding-left:1px !important;
padding-right:1px !important;
```

}

This is PF generic class, so you may need to check your other alignments.